# Is there a way to see whats "stuck" on Gearman-Job-Server?

Tags: gearman

I have Ubuntu/LAMP install of gearman-job-server.

4 have been running on various server sizes; but 1 has 6% cpu and 33% mem (and growing, slowly).

I would like to inspect that job servers processes. Is there a way to do so? This is a package installed via Apt